# Data Sync between Ignite Cluster

Tags: database, caching, ignite

We have two Apache Ignite Clusters (Cluster_A and Cluster_B) of version 2.13.0.

We are writing data into Cluster_A tables. We want to sync/copy the data into Cluster_B tables from Cluster_A.

Is there any efficient way?

Data Sync between Apache Ignite Clusters.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it could be possible to leverage the [CDC replication using Kafka](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/streaming/kafka-streamer) to transfer updates from one cluster to another. But it's totally worth mentioning that it would require running and maintaining a separate Kafka cluster to store updates.

On the other hand, GridGain Enterprise has built-in functionality [Data Center Replication](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/data-center-replication#data-center-replication) the cross data center replication cases. It doesn't require any 3rd party installations, GridGain stores updates in a persistent and reliable manner using [native persistence](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/persistence/native-persistence). It's also possible to establish [active-active](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/data-center-replication/configuring-replication#active-active-mode) replication out of the box.
Another advantage is that GridGain DR has a dedicated [functionality](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/data-center-replication/managing-and-monitoring#full-state-transfer) to transfer the entire state of a cluster.
To get more info about how to configure DCR follow at [link](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/data-center-replication/configuring-replication#configuring-replication).

Comment: Is there any way in Open source Apache Ignite apart from CDC replication using Kafka?